# How to move 3D Model Position THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a walking 3D model in three.js. I have both the [3D model](https://www.mixamo.com/#/?limit=96&page=1&query=man&type=Character) and the [in place fbx walking animation](https://www.mixamo.com/#/?limit=96&page=1&query=walking&type=Motion%2CMotionPack) from Mixamo imported into my project. The model and animation works as expected; the model "walks" due to the loaded animation but stays in the same position. My problem is trying to get the position of the model to increment each frame to give the illusion that the model is walking forwards.

Here is my code:

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { FontLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader';
import { TextGeometry } from 'three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import { Reflector } from 'three/examples/jsm/objects/Reflector.js';
import { FirstPersonControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { FBXLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader';


let glow = 0.05;
let clock = new THREE.Clock();


/* CREATE CAMERA */

  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 4000);
  camera.position.setZ(1);
  camera.position.setX(200);
  camera.position.setY(10);
  // camera.lookAt(50, 0, -1200);

/* END CAMERA */


/* CREATE SCENE & FOG */

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var setcolor = 0x3A4544;
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(setcolor);
  //scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(setcolor, 0, 4000);

/* END SCENE & FOG */



/* CREATE RENDERER */

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  renderer.setAnimationLoop( animation );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

/* END RENDERER */


/* CREATE ORBIT CONTROLS */

  const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  // const controls = new FirstPersonControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  // controls.movementSpeed = 50;
  // controls.lookSpeed = 0.05;
  // controls.lookVertical = true;
  // controls.constrainVertical = true

/* END ORBIT CONTROLS */


/* CREATE LIGHTS */

  const rectLight = new THREE.RectAreaLight( 0xf9d71c, glow, 150, 100 );
  scene.add( rectLight );
  rectLight.position.set( -8, 100, -290 );
  rectLight.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

  const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xaaaaaa, 0.15)
  ambientLight.position.set( 200, 100, 0 );
  ambientLight.lookAt( -300, -300, -300 );
  scene.add(ambientLight)

/* END LIGHTS */


/* CREATE CITY */

  // Floor
  let groundMirror1, geometry;
  geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2500, 2500 );
  groundMirror1 = new Reflector( geometry, {
    clipBias: 0.003,
    color: new THREE.Color(0x212227),
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    mixBlur: 5    
  });

  groundMirror1.position.y = -50
  groundMirror1.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2);

  scene.add( groundMirror1 );




  // 3D Building Font
  let text = "JOHN JACOBS";
  let textMesh;

  const loader = new FontLoader();
  loader.load('node_modules/three/examples/fonts/droid/droid_serif_regular.typeface.json', function (font) {
    const textGeometry = new TextGeometry(text, {
      font: font,
      size: 40,
      height: 1,
      curveSegments: 12,
      bevelEnabled: true,
      bevelThickness: 2,
      bevelSize: 2,
      bevelOffset: 2,
      bevelSegments: 2
    });

    textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, [
      new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ emissive: 0xf9d71c, emissiveIntensity: glow }),
      new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff })
    ]);

    scene.add( textMesh );

    textMesh.position.y = 1685;
    textMesh.position.x = -2000;
    textMesh.position.z = 250;
    textMesh.rotation.y = ( Math.PI / 2 );
  });


  // 3D Models
  const gltfLoader1 = new GLTFLoader();
  gltfLoader1.load('models/building2/scene.gltf', (gltfScene1) => {
    gltfScene1.scene.scale.set( 20, 20, 20 );
    gltfScene1.scene.position.x = 20;
    gltfScene1.scene.position.z = 180;
    gltfScene1.scene.position.y = -50;
    scene.add(gltfScene1.scene);
  });

  const gltfLoader2 = new GLTFLoader();
  gltfLoader2.load('models/building3/scene.gltf', (gltfScene2) => {
    gltfScene2.scene.scale.set( 80, 80, 80 );
    gltfScene2.scene.position.x = -75;
    gltfScene2.scene.position.z = -400;
    gltfScene2.scene.position.y = -1410;
    gltfScene2.scene.rotation.y = ( - Math.PI / 2 )
    scene.add(gltfScene2.scene);
  });

  const gltfLoader3 = new GLTFLoader();
  gltfLoader3.load('models/building4/scene.gltf', (gltfScene3) => {
    gltfScene3.scene.scale.set( 70, 70, 70 );
    gltfScene3.scene.position.x = -500;
    gltfScene3.scene.position.z = 300;
    gltfScene3.scene.position.y = 75;
    scene.add(gltfScene3.scene);
  });

  const gltfLoader4 = new GLTFLoader();
  gltfLoader4.load('models/main_building/scene.gltf', (gltfScene4) => {
    gltfScene4.scene.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
    gltfScene4.scene.position.x = -2600;
    gltfScene4.scene.position.z = -450;
    gltfScene4.scene.position.y = 75;
    gltfScene4.scene.rotation.y = ( Math.PI / 2);
    scene.add(gltfScene4.scene);
  });

  const gltfLoader5 = new GLTFLoader();
  gltfLoader5.load('models/building5/scene.gltf', (gltfScene5) => {
    gltfScene5.scene.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
    gltfScene5.scene.position.x = -2600;
    gltfScene5.scene.position.z = -500;
    gltfScene5.scene.position.y = 275;
    scene.add(gltfScene5.scene);
  });

  // 3D model and walking animation
  let mixer;
  const zomLoader = new FBXLoader();
  zomLoader.load('models/characters/Ch44_nonPBR.fbx', (fbx) => {
    
    fbx.position.x = -500;
    fbx.position.z = 0;
    fbx.position.y = -50;
    fbx.rotation.y = ( Math.PI / 2 );
    fbx.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );

    const anim = new FBXLoader();
    anim.load('models/characters/Walking.fbx', (anim) => {
      mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(fbx);
      const idle = mixer.clipAction(anim.animations[0]);
      idle.play();
    })
    scene.add(fbx)
  });

/* END CITY */


/* CREATE WINDOW RESIZE FUNCTION */

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false)
  function onWindowResize() {
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
      animation()
  }

/* END WINDOW RESIZE FUNCTION */



/* CREATE MAIN ANIMATION FUNCTION */

  animation();
  function animation() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animation );

    //I've tried these two options 
    //fbx.position.x += 0.5;
    //zomLoader(fbx).position.x += 0.5;


    glow = Math.random() - 0.01;
    textMesh.material[0].emissiveIntensity = glow;
    rectLight.intensity = glow;


    if(mixer){
      mixer.update(clock.getDelta());
    }


    //controls.update( clock.getDelta() );
    controls.update();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

  }

/* END MAIN ANIMATION FUNCTION */
```

I'm still new to three.js, and the only times I've moved any object were meshs, not imported 3D models. I'm used to using `mesh.position.x += 1` inside the main animation function, but when I try to apply that to the model using `fbx.position.x += 1`, the scene disappears. How can I move the 3D model position to give the illusion the model is walking along the x-axis?

**EDIT**

I figured it out. I added a global variable `let human;`, assigned it to `fbx` and used `human.position.x += 1` in the main animation function. Cheers.

Comment: Also can try `human.translateZ(0.1);` to move 'forward'